# Page load image size/position script randomly not running

Tags: jquery, html, image, object, center

I have a jQuery script that centers my logo on the middle of the screen. It is set up to run on page load and window resize. It works every time on window resize, and 9 times out of 10 on load. But once in a while it completely fails to run on load.

Website at http://vividconference.tv/beta/, and the script in question:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
       var height = $('#logo').height();
       $('#logo').css('margin-top', + height / -2 + 'px');
    }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Why do you call `resize()` at the end of your function?

Comment: @mimo -- it triggers the `resize` function on DOM ready.

Comment: you should do a function, and call it on document ready and on window resize, like a separate function, bye.

Comment: Are you talking about when it just gets stuck saying "Loading your experience, hold tight"?

Comment: If you reload the page a couple of times occasionally the logo will shift down instead of being in the center. It just acts like the script didn't run, because if you resize the page it jumps back to the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that if the image has not been loaded yet, the height will be `0`.

Let's try this for a more comprehensive coverage:

```
function redraw() {
    var height = $('#logo').height();
    $('#logo').css('margin-top', (height / -2) + 'px');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(redraw).resize(redraw);
    $('#logo, #logo img').ready(redraw);
    redraw();
});
```